# CSS Sub Menu shows up outside body

Tags: css, position, submenu

I have tried to find an answer to my question, and while there are similar issues, nothing jumped out as me as a fix for my problem.

I am adding a Sub menu using CSS and for some reason the horizontal sub menu will only show up outside of the body. You can see an example of what happens here http://jsfiddle.net/sxP94/22/.

I need to get the sub menu to appear right under Portfolio on the menu. If anybody could help me figure out why this is happening, I would be ever so grateful.

Here is the code:

CSS

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
color:#929292;
font:normal 12px/1.5em "Liberation sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
html, .main {
padding:0;
margin:0;
} 
.main {
background:#f8f8f8;
}

a {
color:#0087c7;
text-decoration:underline;
}
.header, .content, .menu_nav, .fbg, .footer, form, ol, ol li, ul, .content .mainbar, .content .sidebar {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.header {
}
.header_resize {
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
width:960px;
}

h1 a, h1 a:hover {
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}
h1 span {
}

.menu_nav {
margin:0 auto;
padding:70px 0 0;
height:15px;
float:right;
}
.menu_nav ul {
list-style:none;
padding:0 0 0 1px;
height:15px;
float:left;
background:url(../images/menu_split.gif) no-repeat left center;
}
.menu_nav ul li:first-child {
margin:0;
}
.menu_nav ul li {
margin:0;
padding:0 20px;
float:left;
background:url(../images/menu_split.gif) no-repeat right center;
}
.menu_nav ul li a {
display:block;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-size:15px;
line-height:18px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#c4c4c4;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
.menu_nav ul li.active a, .menu_nav ul li a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
}
.menu_nav > ul > li > ul {
height:1000px;
left:-99999px;
overflow:visible;
position:absolute;
top:37px;
width:115px;
float: left;

}
.menu_nav > ul > li:hover ul {
left:0;
top:37px;
}
.menu_nav > ul > li > ul > li {
background:none #343434;
border:1px solid #4f4f4f;
float:none;
height:29px;
margin:-1px 0 0;
padding:0 12px;
position:relative;
width:auto;
z-index:1000;
}
.menu_nav ul li ul li a {
color:#ffffff!important;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
line-height:28px;
text-transform:none;

}
.menu_nav ul li ul li.active a, .menu_nav ul li ul li a:hover {
color:#fff!important;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="header">
<div class="header_resize">
  <div class="menu_nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html"><span>About</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html"><span>Services</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html"><span>Portfolio</span></a>
            <ul>
        <li><a href="boudoir.html">Boudoir</a></li>
        <li><a href="babies.html">Babies</a></li>
        <li><a href="engagement.html">Engagement</a></li>
        <li><a href="wedding.html">Wedding</a></li>
        <li><a href="lifestyle.html">Lifestyle</a></li>
        <li><a href="family.html">Family</a></li>
        <li><a href="grad.html">Grads</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      <li><a href="blog.html"><span>Blog</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Anytime I change any of the left numbers, the sub menu stops showing up completely. Doesn't even show up on the outside of the body when I hover over the menu. So I can't figure out how to move it around because anything I try makes it disappear completely. Thank you for taking the time to read this and thank you in advance for any help you are able to offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `position: relative` to parent of the sub menu. The sub menu is given `position:absolute` and hence shows up outside.

```
.menu_nav ul li {
 position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried that and it does move it, however it puts a space between the items on the parent menu that I can't figure out. You can see it here after the position has been changed to relative - http://jsfiddle.net/sxP94/26/ - As you can see, there is now a space in between 'portfolio' and 'blog' and it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Awesome! That fixed the positioning, however, NOW the submenu is not clickable. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. The top had to be changed to 0px under the hover. Thanks again!